# Netbeans SQL select column names with # in the

Tags: netbeans

I have an odd problem with netbeans (6.7.1). Using the built in SQL editor I cannot select any column defined with a # in it's name. It appears that Netbeans is treating this a comment and never passing to the underlying connection. Is there a way to change this?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

If you have any control over the column names, I suggest you remove the # symbols.  NetBeans is not the only application that will choke on them.

Comment: This is a heavy utilized legacy DB. The best I can do is create a view with the fields renamed (which I would have to do outside Netebeans at this point).